# ejecutar consulta TOP 1, JDBC

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

tengo una aplicacacion en android que se conecta a una base de datos mediante JDBC, y al hacer una consulta con top 1, me entrega el siguiente error:

> java.sql,SQLEXCEPTION: use of the execute query(String) method is not supported on this type of stament

y esta es la consulta en cuestion

```
select top 1 * from reporte where nombre_ruta = 'nombre_ruta' order by fecha desc;
```

la consulta en la base de datos funciona perfectamente, espero puedan guiarme :)

---

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    try {
String query = "select top 1 nombre_ruta,descripcion from reporte where nombre_ruta = '"+marker.getTitle()+"';";
                            con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
                            if (con == null) {
                                isConnected(getApplicationContext());
                            } else {
                                stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                                stmt.setQueryTimeout(1);
                                rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                   reporte = rs.getString("nombre_ruta");
                                    descripcion=rs.getString("descripcion");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estás usando un `PreparedStatement`, no debes pasarle el parámetro `query` a la llamada:

```
stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

La llamada deberia ser simplemente (sin parámetros):

```
stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: pero si quito el parámetro, como sabrá que es esa la consulta?

Comment: Lo sabrá porque ya lo especificaste en esta sentencia: `stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)`. Pruébalo y verás.

Comment: no me di cuenta, jajaja, gracias :D